# How to connect a jack lead to the input of a 741 circuit

Tags: voltage-divider, microphone

Below is a diagram of a 741 circuit with a microphone attached, I've built the circuit and it works reasonably well. However is it possible to connect a jack lead to the circuit instead of a microphone? So I could connect a mobile phone to the circuit and play music into the circuit and the LEDs would sort of flash in time.

[image: 741 diagram]
<sub>(source: [reconnsworld.com](http://www.reconnsworld.com/audio/electretamp.gif))</sub>

Comment: Where are those LEDs? (And from which museum did you nick that 741 chip? in other words: that is a *very* old-fashioned chip! and it was never intended to work on a single-ended 5V supply)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can connect whatever you want, assuming you have physical access.  You won't need to connect the jack to the +5 V, just ground and the input.

Whether this does what you want is impossible to say since you haven't specified what that is.  Note that the output of a mobile phone probably has a few 100 to 1000 times higher voltage.